# Why is my root folder for apache not changing?

Tags: apache2

I am trying to configure apache and I created a directory in /srv/www because I want my default root folder there instead of /var/www. I opened the config file in /apache2/sites-available (and properly linked the sites-enabled to this config file) and this is what it looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.

        serverAlias extracurricular.com
        ServerAdmin lleeoo66@extracurricular.com
        DocumentRoot /srv/www/extracurricular.com

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None

        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Mult

iViews

        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        # Possible values are: debug, info, not ice, warn, error, crit, alert, emerg
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/extracurricular.com_access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

My ip to my vps is: http://192.99.246.96/

It is just bringing me to the /var/www folder and not /srv/www/extracurricular.com (my domain name). Why is this?

P.S. I have a simple index.html in my /extracurricular.com directory

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName  extracurricular.com
    #serverAlias www.extracurricular.com
    ServerAdmin lleeoo66@extracurricular.com
    DocumentRoot /srv/www/extracurricular.com

    <Directory "/srv/www/extracurricular.com">
            Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
            DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    # Possible values are: debug, info, not ice, warn, error, crit, alert, emerg
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/extracurricular.com_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: @ Muru: That is actually an answer.
**Alexander:** please state more clearly the changes you did by using text like "Add: `ServerName  extracurricular.com`and remove serveralias etc... (keep in mind that you're answering a reputation 13 user and what is *obvious*  to you and me is difficult enough to post a question here for the person that is installing his first server...)  ;-)

Comment: @Fabby I understand the changes that are made and why I have to make them. You are however right on the money, as this is my first server, and I am entirely new to this.

Comment: @ripjerry: could you [edit] the answer then and make it more clear for the next user who doesn't?  (I've got my hands full with other stuff on the site)

Comment: @Fabby Wow I didnt know I could edit the answers, thanks!

Comment: It'll get to someone (like me) who has to review your edits, so don't do anything crazy!  :P  ;-)